# can't print string and boolean value together in java

Tags: java

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String man1="All man are created equal:27";
        final String man2="All man are created equal:"+man1.length();
        System.out.print("All man are created equal:"+man1==man2);
    }
}
```

why only false is getting printed instead of the whole print statement.

Comment: Because `("All man are created equal:"+man1)==man2` is false

Comment: Java operations order is **left-associative**, thus `+` first, then `==` evaluated

Answer (score 1):

Because of [Operator Precedence](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)

`==` is below `+`, so first it will evaluate the string concatenation (`+`) and then their equality (`==`)

The order will be:

1. `+`: "All man are created equal:" + man1 => "All man are created equal:All man are created equal:27"
2. `==`: "All man are created equal:All man are created equal:27" == man2 => false
3. `System.out.println(false)`

**Bonus** use `equals` to compare strings (objects)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String man1 = "All man are created equal:28";
    final String man2 = "All man are created equal:" + man1.length();

    System.out.println(("All man are created equal:" + man1) == man2);
    System.out.println("All man are created equal:" + (man1 == man2));
    System.out.println("All man are created equal:" + man1.equals(man2));
}
```

Output

```
false
All man are created equal:false
All man are created equal:true
```

Comment: can you please elaborate more please

Comment: @pranaysaha All the operators have an evaluation priority, you will have to respect that priority or you can add parenthesis to define a custom evaluation order

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in this statement -

```
 System.out.print("All man are created equal:"+man1==man2);
```

here a new string (say `s1`) is generated with the concatenation of `All man are created equal:` and `man1`.
Now you have  2 references of string `s1` and `man1`.
Later these two string references - `s1` and `man2` are compared.

both references(`s1` and `man2`) are different and you are getting false.